# Pass all mouse events from parent to child component - Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component that I want to pass all mouse events that occurs inside to a child component that contain 3 different component that are depended on the data that being pass.
**My goal is not to use an event listeners inside the parent component, but inside the child component and handle all the logic inside the child component**

At first I thought about creating a directive with `@HostListners` instead of a child component and bind it to the parent element, but since there are components inside the child component I didn't go for it.

Any hellp would be appreciated.

**Example:**

```
<div class="some-class"> // Pass all mouse events from here 

 <app-child-component> // To here
   <app-child-of-child-component-1></app-child-of-child-component-1>
   <app-child-of-child-component-2></app-child-of-child-component-2>
   <app-child-of-child-component-3></app-child-of-child-component-3>
 </app-child-component>

</div>
```

Comment: You add an event listener to parent element. When a child element triggers that event, the listener will also fire. You only need to differentiate who was the child that fired the event and handle it according a separated logic

Comment: Why you can't go with HostListner? I believe, it can be caught at any level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a directive to listen to all mouse events

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[appMouseListener]"
})
export class MouseListenerDirective {
  constructor() {}

  private enterSub = new Subject<MouseEvent>();

  public enter = this.enterSub.asObservable();

  @HostListener("mouseenter", ["$event"]) onMouseEnter(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.enterSub.next(event);
  }
}
```

if you need you can filter the events emitted to only emit the parent one. This is the event target would be the parent component element.

```
export class MouseListenerDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef){}

  public enter = this.enterSub.asObservable().pipe(filter(x => x.target === this.el.nativeElement));

...
```

add this directive on parent component

```
<parent-component appMouseListener>
  <child-component></child-component>
</parent-component>
```

Access events on child component by injecting the directive

```
@Component({ // configs}
export class ChildComponent {

  constructor(mouseListener: MouseListenerDirective){
    mouseListener.enter.subscribe(x => console.log(x)); // don't forget to manage subscriptions
  }
}
```